# Modem manager problem on Slackware 15.0

Tags: networkmanager, modem, modem-manager

On syslog of my Slackware 15.0 I see those annoying messages

```
Oct  1 06:41:45 nas NetworkManager[1867]: <warn>  [1696135305.0097] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
Oct  1 06:43:45 nas NetworkManager[1867]: <warn>  [1696135425.0122] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
Oct  1 06:45:45 nas NetworkManager[1867]: <warn>  [1696135545.0116] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
Oct  1 06:47:45 nas NetworkManager[1867]: <warn>  [1696135665.0108] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
Oct  1 06:49:45 nas NetworkManager[1867]: <warn>  [1696135785.0037] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
Oct  1 06:51:45 nas NetworkManager[1867]: <warn>  [1696135905.0029] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
Oct  1 06:53:45 nas NetworkManager[1867]: <warn>  [1696136025.0019] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
Oct  1 06:55:45 nas NetworkManager[1867]: <warn>  [1696136145.0013] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
```

What to check?
Thanks

permissions are those:

```
ls -lhd /usr/sbin/ModemManager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1,8M nov 26  2021 /usr/sbin/ModemManager*
```

Those are permission of serial device, I don't understand who change ttyS02 permissions

```
ls -ld /dev/ttyS*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 ott  8 04:07 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 ott  8 04:07 /dev/ttyS1
crw--w---- 1 root tty     4, 66 ott  8 04:10 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 67 ott  8 04:07 /dev/ttyS3

grep -irl ttyS2 /etc

/etc/default/grub~
/etc/default/grub
/etc/radiusclient/port-id-map
/etc/radiusclient/radiusclient.conf
/etc/securetty
/etc/serial.conf
/etc/inittab~
/etc/inittab
```

I have tried to set permissions as default (root:dialout and 660) to ttyS2 but...

```
Oct  9 21:07:23 nas NetworkManager[1880]: <warn>  [1696878443.0583] modem-manager: error poking ModemManager: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: Permission denied
```

Comment: What's the permission of `org.freedesktop.ModemManager1`? Use `locate ModemManager`. Is it executable?

Comment: `org.freedesktop.ModemManager1` is a reference to [ModemManager's DBus interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/doc/latest/ModemManager/ref-dbus.html), it is not a literal binary program. First thing to check for, permissions on the serial device file.